# duplicate content in different url keys in magento site

Tags: magento, url, seo

we created lot of categories and sub categories and assigned same products to

different categories in magento site.

thiese are url paths generated for products in our site.

"sitename/category one/same product "

"sitename/category two/same product "

how to remove those category names in url paths and put same path for one product in entire site.

"www.sitename.com/product 1 "

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You must go:

System - Configuration - Catalog - Search Engine Optimizations

And set param "Use Categories Path for Product URLs" to No

Comment: i followed your procedure, than if we click on categories and than we will visit product list page and than if we click on product than "category url Path" is removed. but if we type sitename.com/category 1/product 1 and sitename.com/category 2/product 1 in "browser's address bar" than same product information will show in both urls. i want to display only this url in entire site : "sitename.com/product1" url. if we go for "sitename.com/category 1/product 1", it should give error.